# How to load more content with ajax when user scrolls to the bottom the of page only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to append an html file I have to a div when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page. But I only want to do this once. I managed to write a script that works, but I noticed after a few refreshes of the page, it randomly retrieves and appends the HTML more than once. Notice, I'm using a Boolean to control the script to one use,I have a hunch this might be where my problem resides.

This is my script and div that will have content appended to it:

** EDIT: removed the if (used == false) since its unnecessary. **

```js
var used = false;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 400 && used == false) {
          $.get("more.html",function(data){
               $("#new-content").append(data);
                 used = true;
             });
     }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="new-content">

</div>
```

This is the html I want to append

```
    <div class="double-wrapper">
     <div class="app">
      <div class="app-inner"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="app">
      <div class="app-inner"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inn">
     <div class="inn-inner">
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: the `if (used == false) {` test should be inside the event function, the event is set only once, but it's enough for the function to fire a long as there is a scroll. Let the function fire and test inside, or you could remove the event function instead of having a boolean

Comment: I removed if (used == false) all together after a few refreshes of the page and scrolling down, the problem reoccurred and appended the html several times.

Comment: I actually didn't say you should remove it altogether, but only move it inside the `$(window).scroll` function..

Comment: Yes, but I noticed I already have it as an argument in the if $(window).scroll statement, therefore having the if (used == false ) was redundant. I also what you said and placing it in the $(window).scroll and the same problem occurred.

Comment: oh right i hadn't seen it because line is long. Well it can be that the function has time to be fired multiple times before the response arrives, leaving a tiny moment where `used` is still `false`. What i'd do is to implement a second boolean as a 'lock', set to true at the beginning, before the test, and back to false when data arrives. The reason i would use a different boolean is in case you want the first one, `used` to keep track the content has been effectively loaded. If you set the value to true before the response and that it fails, the true value would be wrong

Comment: could you show me a sample of what you mean? I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Sorry I'm a visual learner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example. By using a second boolean to lock the function before any asynchronous call is made, you can keep the original one `used` to keep track that the content has been added successfully. If there is an error in the request (you can try to change the URL by an invalid one), `used` will stay at false and the function can try again the request (i added an error function to release the lock).

```js
    var used = false, locked = false;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
      //I shortened conditions (for a boolean, "!used" is same as "used == false")
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 400 && !used & !locked) {
          //lock function before the call
          locked = true;
          $.get("http://date.jsontest.com",function(data){
               //different injection for the test because i used JSON test content
               //$("#new-content").append(data);
               $("#new-content").html($("#new-content").html() + '<p>' + JSON.stringify(data) + '</p>');
               used = true;
               //release the lock when results arrive
               locked = false;
          }).fail(function(){
               console.log('request has failed');
               //release the lock on error if you want to be able to try the request again
               locked = false;
          });
      }
    });
```

```css
body{
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="new-content">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, now I see what you mean. I just tried this and it seems to be working. Thanks for your patience. The lock Boolean is a pretty clever idea.

Comment: you're welcome, had already some troubles about similar things where that can be useful